# Cannot modify container in azure container apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

When I try to modify a container of azure container apps, I get this error:

> Failed to deploy new revision: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'configuration.Registries.xyz4acr.azurecr.io.PasswordSecretRef' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "xyz4acrazurecrio-xyz4acr": secret reference does not exist'.

I do not remember setting anything like that and do not find a place where I could remove the secret ref (it does not appear in UI on azure portal)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that Azure Container Apps is unable to find the secret reference `xyz4acrazurecrio-xyz4acr` when trying to deploy the new revision of your container app.
As per MSFT employee **[sanchitmehta](https://github.com/sanchitmehta)**, this was a bug as mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/722) which was resolved

As a workaround, you can either create a fresh secret reference or verify the existing secret using the
`kubectl get secret` command to check if the secret referenced in the `PasswordSecretRef` field exists. If it does not exist, you will need to create it.

To create the secret reference, you can use the following steps:

1. Go to the  **Secrets**  section of the Azure portal.
2. Click the  **+ Add**  button.
3. Select the  **Secret**  type.
4. Enter a name for the secret, such as  `xyz4acrazurecrio-xyz4acr`.
5. Enter the value of the secret.
6. Click the  **Create**  button.

[image]

Once the secret has been created, you can add the secret reference to the container app configuration. To do this, go to your  **Container Apps**  and click the name of your container app. Create a secret with  `Key Vault Reference`  pointing to the secret in the key vault and  `Managed identity`  as  `System assigned` and add a reference to the secret when adding environmental variables to the app with  `--set-env-vars Auth0__ClientSecret=secretref:auth0-client-secret`  or select it from the dropdown in the portal.
Save it.
[image]

Once you have made the necessary changes to the container app configuration, you can deploy the new revision.